# Does a "worker" in mstest parallel testing have a unique id?

Tags: c#, multithreading, mstest, worker

I am working with MSTest, and I was wondering if Parallelize workers have a unique ID, and if so, how can I get those IDs?  I assumed `1 worker = 1 thread`, however `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadID` is not unique to the worker.  I require a way to get a unique ID of the worker in question.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

This is what I am working with

```
[assembly: Parallelize(Workers =1, Scope = ExecutionScope.ClassLevel)]
```

I want to say 2 workers, and have 2 different classes. Each class I want to run at the same time.

When I start up a worker, I create a new object into my manager, See `ThreadManager` below.  However, as you can see, the method I am using in order to get the current thread will not apply to more than 1 worker.

```
public static class ThreadManager
{
    public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
    private static Dictionary<int, ThreadObject> threadDictionary;

    static ThreadManager()
        => threadDictionary = new Dictionary<int, ThreadObject>();

    public static void AddThread()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("AppSettings.json");
        Configuration = builder.Build();

        threadDictionary.Add(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, new ThreadObject());
        }

    public static void RemoveThread()
            => threadDictionary.Remove(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    public static ThreadObject GetThread()
    {
        ThreadObject _thread = null;
            threadDictionary.TryGetValue(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, out _thread);
        return _thread;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered whether you're solving the wrong problem here? Why, *specifically* is this a problem that only needs addressing during testing but not one that's going to arise in real usage?

Comment: I require access to a driver from a static class.  This static class needs to be able to identify which worker its working with.  I built it this way due to some complicated reasons.  This method works when we had a selenium grid and working with NUnit3 but as soon as we switched to MSTest V2 and ditched the grid, we go this issue.

I could spend some time trying to re-build but it would be easier to know if i can get a unique ID that is assigned to the worker, that the application get get a hold of.

Comment: is this the one? https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx if so looks like you are out of luck.